# Examples of locally finite set whose convex hull is the whole $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: discrete-geometry

In our exercise a locally finite set A is a set such that $A \cap B(r)$ is a finite set for all $r \geq 0$, where $B(r)$ is the ball centered at $0$ and has radius $r$. Shouldn't conv($A$) then be bounded?

Comment: Seems to me that you can take point in different direction such that distance form origin is +1 each next point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $A=\mathbb{Z}^n$. Then
$$\vert A \cap B(r)\vert \leq (2r)^n <\infty.$$
But surely the convex hull of $A$ is all of $\mathbb{R}^n$.